# RabbitMQ connectivity with Load Balancer(Tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I have a cluster of RabbitMQ servers(typically 2).

How could i load balance between the cluster. Does TOMCAT provide any server for this? or what would be the best LoadBalancer here?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your question. 
HA and Federation are RabbitMQ configurations what's the rules about `tomcat` ?

Comment: I have a cluster of RabbitMQ servers(typically 2).

How could i load balance between the cluster. Does TOMCAT provide any server for this? or what would be the best LoadBalancer here?